# How can I use custom fonts in an HTML5 Canvas element?

Tags: html, canvas, fonts, cufon, typeface.js

I've looked at things like Cufon and typeface.js but they seem to be SIFR alternatives and don't allow you to set freeform coordinates and draw custom type onto a `<canvas>`

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

I've thrown together a simple demo on jsfiddle here showing how to do this with @font-face: http://jsfiddle.net/zMKge/

Opera also has a [simple tutorial](https://dev.opera.com/articles/html5-canvas-basics/) on using `<canvas>`, including the text API.

CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'KulminoituvaRegular';
    src: url('http://www.miketaylr.com/f/kulminoituva.ttf');
}
```

Javascript:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('c').getContext('2d');
var kitty = new Image();
kitty.src = 'http://i954.photobucket.com/albums/ae30/rte148/891blog_keyboard_cat.gif';
kitty.onload = function(){
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0,0,this.width, this.height);
  ctx.font         = '68px KulminoituvaRegular';
  ctx.fillStyle = 'orangered';
  ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
  ctx.fillText  ('Keyboard Cat', 0, 270);
};
```

Comment: Be aware of this issue, though : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756575/drawing-text-to-canvas-with-font-face-does-not-work-at-the-first-time

Comment: The Firefox issue is because the browser is very strict on its same-origin policy. Stars have to align and *image, font, and webpage must ALL be on the same domain*

Comment: This doesn't work in Chrome 21, but works on FF 7, 12 and 15. All on Windows 7.

Comment: This doesn't work (reliably) on the BlackBerry Playbook browser. At best it works when refreshing the page; sometimes the font doesn't show at all.

Comment: This does not work at all on Safari 6.0.5 or Chrome 27.0.1453.116, both running on OS X 10.8.4. Safari's behavior when an unavailable font is used is to display nothing; Chrome uses Arial.

Comment: I couldn't get that JSFiddle to work so I updated it using a Google Webfont.  http://jsfiddle.net/zMKge/2171/

Answer (score 8):

I have just answered this question here: [Preload font HTML5, JS, Kinetic.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540591/preload-font-html5-js-kinetic-js/15973926#15973926)

The essential part:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'myfont';
    src: url('myfont.eot');
    src: url('myfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('myfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('myfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('myfont.svg#myfont') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

It should not matter if you are using KineticJS or not, the only difference without KineticJS is that you would possibly create the Canvas element directly with HTML instead of using a div layer as container. After all KineticJS just creates a normal Canvas element in that container.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: in that case i´d say it´s ok, because it links to stackoverflow ;) - but i will include the essential part.

Answer (score 2):

an answer from 3 years into the future lol

you can user javascript's `new FontFace(family, font, descriptor)`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFace/FontFace

where family is the name of the font, font is a url or ttf binary data, and descriptor is css elements.

then use `ctx.fillText()` to create the text

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this worked.

Define the link with preload inside the `head` tag, and specify its font inside the `style` tag. When you draw it on the canvas, you should also specify the family name of the font and use functions like `fillText()`.

```
<head>
    <link rel="preload" href="myfont.woff" as="font" type="font/woff" crossorigin>
    <style>
        .cls {
            font-family: 'myfont_familyname';
            src: url('myfont.woff') format('woff');
        }
    </style>
</head>
```