# How do I wait for first canvas-repaint until @font-face-font is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, font-face

I have a HTML5-canvas and write text with `context.fillText(...);` using a @font-face-font.
Displaying the page with Firefox (3.6) I have the problem, that on the first paint of the canvas the font is not downloaded yet so the text will be displayed with a standard-font.
I found a 'solution' [here](http://paulirish.com/2009/fighting-the-font-face-fout/) but it does not work, because the font is only used in the canvas and the canvas is loaded and displayed with ajax using jQuery.
Is there any better solution than trying to use a timeout `setTimeout(repaintCanvas, 500);`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756575/drawing-text-to-canvas-with-font-face-does-not-work-at-the-first-time/8223555#8223555

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found a solution with the help of Reigel's answer:

```
$.get('font/url.ttf', function() {
    // do canvas codes.... cause font is loaded...
});
```

Additionally use the font via `font-family: 'fontfacename';` for the canvas' parent-element.
Could be that the font is loaded twice, don't know. But without the second load it won't be displayed right.

Answer (score 4):

well, you could try this,

```
$.get('font/url.ttf',function(){
   // do canvas codes.... cause font is loaded...
});
```

Comment: Thanx, but won't work. The font-file will be loaded but I think the browser does not recognoze that it's also the file for the @font-face.