# Writing text using canvas in HTML5

Tags: html, canvas, character-encoding, html5-canvas

I have used the following code to write text using canvas.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function convert(){
      draw(document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d'));
    }

    function draw(txt){
      var fillText="Some text";
      txt.textBaseline="top";
      txt.font="Arial";
      txt.fillStyle="red";
      txt.fillText(fillText,20,20);
    }

  </script>
</head>
  <body onload="convert()">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

My question is: is it possible to write text in other languages also?

Comment: Could you give an example of what you want to do?

Comment: The above code would create a text 'Some text' using canvas, i want the same using other languages

Comment: you can do this with as3. Take a textfield and use this as parameter of the draw method from BitmapData Objects

Comment: What do you mean by "other languages"? Like German, French, Japanese? Sure, what's stopping you from doing so?

Comment: that’s not an example of what you want to do. All you’ve done is re-stated what you said in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as the font you use supports the other language's character sets there should be no problems.

If the font is not a common font (And a Japanese/Arabic/Hebrew font isn't) you should use `@font-face` to supply the font file.

Yuo can read this thread: [Drawing text to <canvas> with @font-face does not work at the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756575/drawing-text-to-canvas-with-font-face-does-not-work-at-the-first-time) for a common gotcha.