# Embed font in Canvas Context using html5 for Android , PhoneGap, iOS

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, cordova

We are developing our apps HTML5/CSS/JavaSript.
These apps would be embedded in a native shell/container application for Android and iOS.
(We will use PhoneGap to deploy Android and iOS app).
We need to embed dynamic or run time font in HTML->canvas->context.
(context filltext(....) does not support dynamic text)
How we can embed dynamic font in context.

<style>
    @font-face { font-family: gurblipi; src: url('gurblipi.ttf') format('truetype');}
    p { font-family: gurblipi, serif; }
    h1 { font-family: gurblipi, serif; }
    canvas { font-family: gurblipi, serif; }

</style>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "#a34567";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillRect (10,10,280,280);
    // The gurblipi is in the same folder , we need to embed it
    ctx.font = '32px "gurblipi"';  
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)";
    ctx.fillText("Text Test here...", 80, 225);

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756575/drawing-text-to-canvas-with-font-face-does-not-work-at-the-first-time