# Using google webfonts with canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fonts

I'm getting a strange bug with my google webfonts and canvas.

When I try to use the font in canvas alone it doesn't work, but if I add a `<h1>` on the same page with the same font, suddenly the font in the canvas works (without changing the code).

So I tried to solve it by setting the h1 to `display:none` but then the font stopped working inside the canvas again.

Why is it acting like this? The code is below:

```
ctx.font = 'bold 20px VT323';
ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
ctx.fillText('Hello World', 30, 25);
```

The link to the google font is inside the `<head>` tag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drawing text to <canvas> with @font-face does not work at the first time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756575/drawing-text-to-canvas-with-font-face-does-not-work-at-the-first-time)

Comment: Maybe browser don't download webfont if it's not used (apply by css into html element)

Comment: @jcubic yeah it worked if I applied it to canvas in css. Change your comment to answer if you want credit

Comment: instead of display: none , use margin-left : -2000px for instance.

Comment: problem was solved by putting a font: style for the canvas in the stylesheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe browser don't download webfont if it's not used (apply by css into html element)