# Preloading the correct @font-face font with JS

Tags: javascript, font-face

Is it possible to preload @font-face files for later use?

Ideally I'd like to:

- Detect the correct font file for the browser (woff, eot, ttf, etc) and preload it
- Detect when the font has been loaded, to trigger further events

This will form part of a [preloader](https://github.com/nandastone/precook-backbone) tool that will calculate progress and block page interaction. This generally rules out browser based solutions such as prefetch.

Comment: This question may help:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756575/drawing-text-to-canvas-with-font-face-does-not-work-at-the-first-time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756575/drawing-text-to-canvas-with-font-face-does-not-work-at-the-first-time)

Comment: Checking '@font-face' load: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12312323/how-to-know-if-a-font-font-face-has-already-been-loaded/12316349#12316349

Answer (score -1):

You can dynamically add a style element to the head, and have your font-face declaration in that.

Then, you can dynamically add a class to any element, to which you can apply the font-family value for your font.

No need to play with preload.

Comment: I _want_ to play with preload. font-face files can be quite large, and I'd like to know when the file has finished downloading.