# Chromecast receiver application not showing custom font

Tags: javascript, html, fonts, chromecast, google-cast

I followed the instructions to load a custom font in a html canvas text field. It works fine when I open the page with the Desktop Chrome browser but when I open it with the Chromecast receiver application the font is not loaded. What could be the problem?

Defining the custom font:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

@font-face {
  font-family: 'myfont';
  src: url('myfont.TTF') ;
}
```

Actual text:

```
ctx.font = "30px myfont";
ctx.fillText("MyText:",50, 50);
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the remote debugging console for your receiver?

Comment: It did not show any errors unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that apparently the font was not loaded, using the solution from [Drawing text to <canvas> with @font-face does not work at the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756575/drawing-text-to-canvas-with-font-face-does-not-work-at-the-first-time), placing the

```
<div style="font-family: PressStart;">.</div>
```

in the preload made it working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Styled Media Receiver](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/styled_receiver) that allows the sender to play media on a Cast device without creating your own custom receiver application by providing your own CSS file during registration.

Here are the list of [Pre-installed fonts](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/receiver_apps#fonts) that can be used with the receiver:

> - Droid Sans, sans-serif
> - Droid Sans Mono, monospace
> - Droid Serif Regular, serif
> - Cutive Mono
> - Short Stack
> - Quintessential
> - Alegreya Sans SC

Here are the [classes](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/styled_receiver#css) that can be used in SMR:

> - `.background:` The background for the receiver.
> - `.logo:` The logo shown when the receiver is launching. This class is also used when the receiver is in the idle state and no .splash
>     class is declared.
> - `.progressBar:` The progress bar for media playback.
> - `.splash:` The screen shown when the receiver is in an idle state. If this class is not declared, the receiver will default to .logo or
>     the app name.
> - `.watermark:` A watermark shown when the media is playing.

Comment: This is not applicable as I am using a custom receiver