# KonvaJS: HTML in a Text object

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, kineticjs, konvajs

I'm currently looking into KonvaJS to create like a scrap booking app, and i'm trying to display like a bullet list.

I trying to use a Text shape and add html to the text to see if it will render it, but no luck.

Is this even possible? If so, how? If not, what other ways does KonvaJS have to display fancy text, like lists, bold ext...

```
    var text = new Konva.Text({
      text: '<div>this is normal text\n\n <b>This is BOLD</b> </div>',
      fontSize: 8,
      fontFamily: 'Calibri',
      fill: '#555',
      width: 300,
      padding: 20,
      align: 'center',
      stroke: 'black',
      strokeEnabled: false,
      strokeWidth: 0
    });
```

Output:
Sorry, I don`t have enough reputation to post images, but the output text is:

```
<div>this is normal text

<b>This is BOLD</b> </div>
```

I want it to be something like:

this is normal text

**This is BOLD**

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I have voted up to encourage you to ask good question such as this one, and to upload images :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually you can load many icons from [font-awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/), and make beautiful web apps:

```js
window.onload = function () {
var stage = new Konva.Stage({
      container: 'container',
      width: 1000,
      height: 1000
    });

    var layer = new Konva.Layer();

    var simpleText = new Konva.Text({
      x: stage.getWidth() / 10,
      y: 15,
      text: "\uf21c",
      fontSize: 300,
      fontFamily: 'FontAwesome',
      fill: 'green'
    });
  layer.add(simpleText);
  stage.add(layer);
  
}
```

```css
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    src: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/konvajs/konva/0.11.1/konva.min.js"></script>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container" style="font-family:'FontAwesome'">dummyText</div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is a reference for the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/35581429/3530081

Answer (score 2):

Konva can't draw html into canvas. You may use different style options for text such as: fontFamily, fontSize, fontStyle, fontVariant (see [docs](http://konvajs.github.io/api/Konva.Text.html)).

Or you can convert html data into image (or canvas element) with [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/), then draw result via `Konva.Image`.