# Is it possible to add a custom font to chart js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to use a external font in my chart made with Chart JS. Does anyone know if that is possible? I've searched trough the documentation but I haven't found a solution.

Comment: Yes it is possible. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608022/how-can-i-use-custom-fonts-in-an-html5-canvas-element). *Note* chart.js uses the `<canvas>` element to draw on, so your question is the same as asking how to use a custom font on the canvas element.

Comment: I understand why you think that my question is a duplicate of the question that you've gave me. But if you take a look at the documentation of Chart JS, you will see that it works differently.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is indeed possible.

Considering you have imported your font (from [GoogleFonts](https://www.google.com/fonts#) for instance),
you just have to edit the `defaultFontFamily` attribute in your [chart options](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration) like this :

```
var options = {
    // 'Raleway' is the name of the fond I imported from GoogleFonts
    defaultFontFamily: Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = "'Raleway'"
}
```

See [Lolka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38304443/4864023) for more information about the `defaultFontFamily` attribute.

A full working example:

```js
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = "Indie Flower";
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.6/Chart.min.js"></script>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Oh I see! Thanks, do you know if I can use it with 1.x versions?

Comment: I have an .ttf file, that I have to use. Is there a way to use that?

Comment: @StijnWesterhof Sure, take a look at MDN's doc about [`@font-face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face). Then you'll just have to replace `"Indie Flower"` (in `Chart.defaults...`) by the name you gave to your imported font (`font-family` attribute of `@font-face`)

Comment: @StijnWesterhof it works but have some delay to load the font. I've add css file and load it on index.html, then use that font on char.js file like below:
`@font-face {
  font-family: "IRANSansMobile";
  src: url("../fonts/IRANSansMobile.ttf");
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "IRANSansMobile";
  src: url("../fonts/IRANSansMobile_bold.ttf");
  font-weight: bold;
}
`
here is chart.js file:
`Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'IRANSansMobile, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif';`

Comment: I tried this with Roboto and didin't work, I'm downloading from google fonts

Answer (score 1):

First result for google `Chart.JS custom font`

From [documentation:](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/)

> There are 4 special global settings that can change all of the fonts
>   on the chart. These options are in Chart.defaults.global.
>
> ...
>
> defaultFontFamily String  "'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial',
>   sans-serif"   Default font family for all text

Comment: That's not answering the OPs question, none of them are custom external fonts.

Comment: Exactly what Spencer Wieczorek says.

Comment: If you see the documentation, you can see, that this is the actual default settings, not options. So you can change this for your custom font family.