# How do I add a new font .ttf file to use in Bokeh?

Tags: python, fonts, bokeh

I want to use the font Opensans in my plots, but I can't find a way to add the .ttf file to Bokeh/Python. 
I found a way to do it for matplotlib, is there a similar way in Bokeh 0.12.2?
[How to use a (random) *.otf or *.ttf font in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726852/how-to-use-a-random-otf-or-ttf-font-in-matplotlib)

Thanks!

Gert

Answer (score 0):

Bokeh renders on HTML canvas, so you will have to follow the guidance in [How can I use custom fonts in an HTML5 Canvas element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608022/how-can-i-use-custom-fonts-in-an-html5-canvas-element) by putting the Bokeh plot in a custom template, then including CSS like:

@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('myfont.ttf') format('truetype');
}

to load the font and make it available. There are various ways to embed bokeh plots and documents into templates. Without knowing more, I can only point you at the docs:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html