# How to embed custom font in bokeh for export_png

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a customized css font that I would like to embed in bokeh plots so that the axes Fonts are styled appropriately. In live HTML, I can add this css independently from the bokeh HTML components. However, when I want to export as png (bokeh uses headless phantomjs and selenium to export), I need to embed this css before the export_png function does its job. I tried "extending" the Figure class and adding **css**, however, this shows up in the final HTML as a link and not as inline css. Is there anyway I can accomplish this ? All I need is the png to render with my customized font.

Answer (score 1):

Bokeh renders to an HTML Canvas, which is a primitive raster drawing area that does  not use or pay attention to CSS. Bokeh exposes the [canvas font property](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_font.asp) via properties on its own models, e.g. to set the font of the major tick labels:

```
p.axis.major_label_text_font = "helvetica"
p.axis.major_label_text_font_size = "5pt"
```

The documentation lists all the general [kinds of text properties](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#text-properties), as well as all the properties [specific to axes](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/axes.html#bokeh.models.axes.Axis).

Presumably to load an external custom font, you would need to also follow the guidance in this SO question to load the font in the first place: [How can I use custom fonts in an HTML5 Canvas element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608022/how-can-i-use-custom-fonts-in-an-html5-canvas-element)

Comment: Thanks bigreddot. Normally if I set my font in the bokeh object to "my_special_font", and then get the bokeh components and embed them in HTML, all I need to do is add my font css to my final HTML page. The bokeh JS does seem to pick it up. In this case, my question is that if I want to export_png my figure (to a file, for example), I need to somehow tell the renderer what my font is. Since bokeh uses a headless browser to do the rendering. I assumed it should be able to understand my css before rendering. I just need to know how to include it before it does the screenshot and exports png.

Comment: Oh I see, that may actually require new development. I am not sure there are currently any hooks to customize the CSS that the headless browser uses. You *might* be able to add CSS to the [`Resources`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/resources.html#bokeh.resources.Resources) object but if you can't make that work, a GitHub issue is the next step.