# How to use other than default sans seriff family on HTML canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

Is there any way to use other font-family in HTML canvas?

```
  ctx.fillStyle = '#FFF';
  ctx.font = '43px Arial';
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
  ctx.fillText(name, 220, 515);
```

This is using Arial and it works as it's in the sans-serif family, but I've tried by using other family and it fails.

I've tried to change Arial to Segoe-UI font like this:

```
ctx.font = '43px Segoe-UI';
```

But still no effect, how can I use segoe font on html canvas?
If there's no way, is it proper if I save that text into images and import as images into the canvas?

Comment: try `fontFamily`

Comment: May help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608022/how-can-i-use-custom-fonts-in-an-html5-canvas-element

Comment: Does your system have that Segoe-UI font installed locally?

Comment: ya already installed and used for other text in the system already @Kaiido

Comment: So in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zj6unh2d/), you can see the text using that font?

Comment: ya i can see that